# best way to define callbacks on objects in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, aurelia

I have a sidebar menu component with a service that holds items in the menu. Multiple sources can then alter the menu as they see fit.

Currently each item implements SidebarItem:

```js
export interface SidebarItem {
    name: string,
    link: Route|string,
    icon ?: string
}
```

However I can catch certain events (click, hover) and would like to have an option to define a callback on the sidebar item itself.

I'd like to know the best way to accomplish this. Should I define two properties on the interface and let everyone decide how they implement it, or are there any options? I don't think sidebar items can be classes, since I don't want a new class for each sidebar item.

If it helps, I can also dispatch the events using the aurelia event aggregator.

PS: If this feels subjective, just read the title as "How to" instead. My proposed method is a wild guess and I don't think it's correct.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to include reference to callback functions in this interface?

Comment: One thing could be providing convention methods which are not needed to be implemented (=> do not put them in the interface), but if you want the feature, you must implement them. Comparable to the Aurelia component life cycle methods (attached, bind, etc.). They are not needed, but if you want to do something before the component is attached, you must implement the method.

Comment: @NitzanTomer sorry if this was unclear. Let's take Angular 2 components as an example. You can create a component class, but you may need to do something when the component is destroyed. Angular 2 way, you would implement the _OnDestroy_ interface on the component and then implement a ngOnDestroy() method on the class.

My problem is similar. When a user clicks, for example, a "Cancel Account" button in the menu, I'd like to show a confirmable dialog.

1/2

Comment: The best way, in my opinion, would be to have the _option_ to implement certain event handler methods on the item - sidebarItem.onClick = function(event) { displayModal() }

My question is about the proper way of cleanly saying that the option is there. If I add something like _onClick ?: some-type_ on the SidebarItem interface, I can get IDE assistance, but I would have to check if the property exists on the item and if so call the event handler, which feels like a hack. I also thought about the Angular way, but I'd still like feedback on this. 2/2

Comment: @MarcScheib Thanks for the input.

This does seem reasonable, however I won't get any IDE assistance doing this and it seems like magic (I spent a _lot of time_ trying to find out how Aurelia calls certain methods, like configureRouter()).

I thought about having interfaces for specific items - HandleOnClick which define just a single method, onClick() or something. But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this on a plain object, not a class. I'd still have to check if the method exists during runtime (or?), but at least the code would be more clear this way.

Comment: Yeah, you should probably just add `onClick?: (e: MyEvent) => void` to the interface. Kinda like in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the following syntax on the interface:

`onClick?: (e: MyEvent) => void`

Thanks to Nitzan Tomer in the comments.